# How to count and echo number of files on computer in total in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch program where it needs to show how many files on total there is on my system.

I have tried with:

```
set cnt=0
for %%A in (*) do set /a cnt+=1
echo %cnt% files on drive
```

I expected it to show me the total number of files on my C: drive but it just showed in the directory where I put the file?

Comment: The `for` command doesn't recurse subdirectories by default. Run `for /?` for more information (see the `/R` parameter, in particular).

Comment: i did but it just says missing operator.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

1. `cd \` change directory to root of C
2. `set /a` the /a flag is made for computation, use it so the script is never confused.
3. `for /r` the /r flag will recurse directories.

`cd \
set /a cnt=0
for /r %%A in (*) do set /a cnt+=1
echo %cnt% files on drive`

Answer (score 0):

To use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) for this task, you would need to make it recursive, but the result is unlikely to be accurate:

```bat
@Set i=0
@For /R C:\ %%A In (*)Do @Set /A i+=1
@Echo(%i%
```

You could also try using `attrib.exe` with `find.exe`, which in my experience will output a higher number of files:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%Attrib.exe" C:\* /S|"%__AppDir__%Find.exe" /V /C ""
```

I have found however, that `where.exe` outputs a greater number of files than `attrib.exe`, *(although I have never investigated this to determine which result is the more accurate, I would side with `where.exe`)*:

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%Where.exe" /R C:\ *|"%__AppDir__%Find.exe" /V /C ""
```

In all cases above, it should go without saying that **running the batch file *as administrator* will produce a more accurate count**.

If you decide to do that, it should by default be run with `%__AppDir__%` as the current directory so you could omit using full paths:

```bat
@Where.exe /R C:\ *|Find.exe /V /C ""
```

If you're sure that your `%PathExt%` variable remains untouched or contains `.EXE`, you could omit the extension too:

```bat
@Where /R C:\ *|Find /V /C ""
```

The quickest method, however, *(which seemed in my previous tests to match the count from `where.exe`)*, is to use the internal `Dir` command with `find.exe`

```bat
@Dir C:\ /B/S/A-D|Find /V /C ""
```